# Html To PDF in CakePhp Using html2pdf Hangs

Tags: cakephp, pdf, html2pdf

I use `html2pdf`, which is based on `TCPDF`, in CakePhp to render `Views` in `PDF`.
However, sometimes the generation hangs, I mean the browser freezes and never receives data.

There is a way to debug such a behavior? In `apache` logs I do not see any kind of error...

```
$this->set(compact('quotation','company','user'));
$view = new View(null, false);
$view->set(compact('quotation','company','user'));
$view->viewPath = 'Quotations';
$view->layout   = 'preventivo';
if ($quotation['Quotation']['quotation_type'] == SERVICE)
{
  $content = $view->render('print_s_template');
  $this->set(compact('content'));
  $this->response->type('pdf');
  $this->render('print');
```

the `print.ctp` has

```
App::import('Vendor', 'HTML2PDF', array('file' => 'html2pdf'.DS.'html2pdf.class.php'));

$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','it');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$html2pdf->Output('exemple.pdf');
```

and the `html` is in `print_s_template.ctp`.

Comment: Check the applications log files. Guess it's php that is running out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution myself. The problem is that I forgot to pass some variables to the View `$view`. And I suppose cake throw an error which, next, `html2pdf` cannot "render".
So: double check that all the variables in the view do exist!